# ServiceWorkerRegistration.showNotification in PWA, bring app to foreground

Tags: notifications, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm showing notification in my PWA. It works and it shows the notification. But i cant seem to find out how to bring the app to foreground if you click the notification (if possible)?

**Usecase:**

A notification is showned to the user while he is on facebook. Then when the user clicks the notification, then i would like my app to go to foreground.

Is this possible when im not working natively?

**Here is my test code:**

```
 navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');
  Notification.requestPermission(function(result) {
    if (result === 'granted') {
      navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
        registration.showNotification('Notification with ServiceWorker');
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my problem was my lack of knowledge! I had not figured out that the onclick handler should be placed in the service-worker.

I found good help here:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications

https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/demos/notification-examples/

Answer (score 0):

You can open a URL within your PWA. It will open it in a new tab in the browser, even if there is a tab already open to your PWA.

```
    handleResponse( event ) {

    console.log( '[Service Worker] Notification click Received. ${event}' );

    if ( event.action && validURL( event.action ) ) {

        clients.openWindow( event.action );

    }

    event.notification.close();

}
```

Comment: Hey. I cant get it to work - proberly im doing something wrong.  But how do you bind the handle response code to my service worker?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how push works. You code is for capturing the user's permission to receive push notifications. In your service worker you will need to handle the push event, which is what I have above.
You will also need to coordinate the user's subscription code from the browser with your push notification service so you can send the notifications.
The code I share handles the incoming push notification and handles the user clicking an action to trigger the page to open.